# Migrate data from InfluxDB into Prometheus

Tags: influxdb, prometheus

I have about 2 years of time-series data in my InfluxDB. I'd like to import it into my Prometheus instance. There doesn't seem to be an import functionality in Prometheus.

I know I could use InfluxDB as a storage for Prometheus but I'd like to avoid having to maintain two systems. Any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you need that? 
Influx seems much more advanced.

Comment: I started running my services on a Kubernetes cluster and most k8s components already natively expose metrics in Prometheus format so I'd like to stick with that. I converted my own services to also export their instrumentation in Prometheus format but the historical data is still in my InfluxDB. I'd like to keep it for trends analysis so it would be great if I could import it into my new Prometheus storage.

Comment: @grdl did you find any way to do this?

Comment: @kadamb No, unfortunately I did not.

Comment: Since Prometheus got the support of remote-write receiver (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#remote-write-receiver) the migration is now possible, I believe. I don't know if there is an existing tool, but I think it won't be difficult to implement one.

As alternative, I'd suggest to try migrating data from InfluxDB to VictoriaMetrics - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmctl.html#migrating-data-from-influxdb-1x
VictoriaMetrics has similar to Prometheus data model and query language.